# How to update reference of button's background images

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I want to update my application's button's background images. It is working fine in simulator if I clean build first. But, when I try to load in iPhone, I am getting old images, instead of updated onces.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a build, **CLEAN ALL TARGETS**?

Comment: Did you uninstall the app first?

Comment: I Cleaned all targets and also uninstalled my app from my iPhone. but this time I lost all images, which are loading perfectly before. Please help me.

Comment: Make sure the strings in your code for the images are case-sensitive equal, on your Mac it doesn't matter but it does on the device

Comment: @tsakoyan, thanks, but my all images are small case - matches with source control and still I have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use images in your iPhone app:

1. Always clean and clean all targets before building if your images have changed.
2. Make sure that the path you provide for the image has the correct case (builds for iphone simulator are case insensitive but not so for iphone device builds).
   [For example: if you have an image named Image.png; Code that uses "image.png" will work on the iphone simulator but not the device]